# What is the syntactic structure of "Béatrix enfant"

Tags: noms, syntaxe

The question is on the highlighted bit in this passage from La Porte étroite by André Gide.

> Je ne puis décrire un visage ; les traits m’échappent, et jusqu’à la couleur des yeux ; je ne revois que l’expression presque triste déjà de son sourire et que la ligne de ses sourcils, si extraordinairement relevés au-dessus des yeux, écartés de l’œil en grand cercle. Je n’ai vu les pareils nulle part… si pourtant : dans une statuette florentine de l’époque de Dante ; et je me figure volontiers que **Béatrix enfant** avait des sourcils très largement arqués comme ceux-là. Ils donnaient au regard, à tout l’être, une expression d’interrogation à la fois anxieuse et confiante, – oui, d’interrogation passionnée. Tout, en elle, n’était que question et qu’attente… Je vous dirai comment cette interrogation s’empara de moi, fit ma vie.

**Question**

What is the syntactic relation between the two words?  (I could not understand it on the model of *infant Jesus* because, while *infant* [seems](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infant) to be an adjective as well as a noun, *enfant* has only a "substantive" tab in [this dictionary entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enfant).)

Is it like *child prodigy*, in which one noun (*child*) modifies another?

If yes, is it the normal word order for the modified noun (*Béatrix*) to precede the modifying noun (much as a noun normally precedes an adjective that modifies it)?

If possible, please give me some other expressions having the same syntactic structure as *Béatrix enfant*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it means "**Béatrix lorsqu'elle était enfant**" or "**Béatrix quand elle était enfant**".

Technically, I would call it a "*nom épithète*": a noun (here "enfant") works as an adjective. Examples can be found [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4661):

- date limite,
- jupe ballon,
- roman-fleuve,
- carte réseau,
- chandail mode,
- sauce pesto

Or [here](http://bbouillon.free.fr/univ/gram/data/nat.htm):

- bénéfice record

Or [here](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/l-apposition-233.php):

- tartes maison
- robe chocolat

All these examples cannot take a comma, while "Béatrix, enfant, ..." is possible. I cannot explain why, but here is an example where it also works with a comma ([source](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/l-apposition-233.php)):

- son père, médecin, ...

Comment: Are you sure it is the same case than the others? I hear it as **Béatrice, enfant, avait des...**, which sounds to work differently than the others examples you gave.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Your comment is interesting. I have no more information than what I wrote.

Comment: The fact that the "adjectif" could be separated by a comma is probably a different question. We call it "adjectif apposé", i.e., separated by a comma. But why can we do it with Béatrice and not with date? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I added an example with "son père, médecin, ..." that also works with a comma.

Comment: @Antonin -- On change de "monde" avec les `,` : *Béatrice enfant* n'est pas du tout la même personne littéraire que *Béatrice bébé* : accoler deux noms pour définir une entité, c'est mélanger le jaune et le bleu pour en faire du *vert* puis le bleu et le rouge pour en faire du *violet*. Sinon on a Béatrice, coloriée en *jaune*, puis Béatrice coloriée en *rouge*, ce qui ne donne pas du tout  le même spectre visuel !

Comment: C'est intéressant, au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enfant) on présente des nuances entre le qualificatif et le déterminatif (A. 1. c)) ; ça semble avoir la fonction d'un [complément du nom](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4289) au final, c'est-à-dire préciser le nom...